# Java Class Structure

Tags: java, coding-style, conventions

I have a problem during a project of mine using Java,
as usual my java classes have the structure:

```
import ...;
import ...;
...
private Type0 myVariable0;
private Type1 myVariable1;
...
...
private Type99 myVariable99;

MyConstructor()
...
MyGetter0();
...
MyGetter99();
MySetters(MyType0 MyVariable0)
...
MySetters(MyType99 MyVariable99)
```

My PHD supervisor complaints all the time that my class structure is not readable due to lots of variables declared, and lots of getters and setters.
I am using Java for my project and I don't know C++, **but I studied his implementation of my project in C++, and he does not use lots of global variables for the whole class, instead he has lots of local variables into functions.**

Is it possible to encapsulate private variables into Java methods only, avoiding to use class member variables? I believe that is not possible. I have tried to restructure my above code but I cannot manage.

Is it the solutions to split the code into multiple classes only,
or is there another **generic** way that I miss to restructure the whole [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_Java_object) structure putting variables into class methods?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's a POJO you're after: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pojo-vs-java-beans/

Comment: Beyond that, it's hard to advise you because we don't know what "ugly" means in this context.

Comment: Ugly is the POJO structure I have indicated in code. My question is can we have a POJO functionality with another structure (i.e. private variables into methods?)

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is a distressingly limited view of what a POJO is.

Comment: @Novemberland what is ugly about that structure? Please edit your question before it's closed

Comment: @Novemberland: Anything is possible given enough time, money and programmer effort.  What does "ugly" mean?  Is the concept of "ugly" at all relevant to getting your work done?

Comment: Ugly I mean not readable from other programmers

Comment: @Novemberland also, please be clear what you mean by "POJO functionality". Again, please edit. Comments rarely save questions.

Comment: I can read it just fine.

Comment: @candied_orange: *shrug* If it were up to me, data transfer objects like this would simply be public variables.  There's no notion of a Property in Java, like C# has, so the fact that this is ugly can be blamed on the language, not the programmer.

Comment: @RobertHarvey to be clear, my complaint about that blog is it implies that all POJO's are beans. This isn't true. POJOs don't have to have a single getter or setter. They can be properly encapsulated behavior objects. Being a POJO is about not being a slave to libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's important to understand proper OOP from a traditional sense, and what is necessary for data binding, etc.  Java introduced the JavaBean (POJO with only getters and setters) to bind to the user interface.  Most people are not building user interfaces in Java these days, but they still have their place.  First, let's distinguish between OOP and traditional procedural programming:

**Object Oriented Programming:**

- Emphasizes data hiding (i.e. internal data is not accessible directly)
- Only exposes methods to manipulate the object
- [SOLID principles](https://williamdurand.fr/2013/07/30/from-stupid-to-solid-code/)

As an example, lets say we have a PlayerCharacter class for a game:

```
public class PlayerCharacter {
    private int defense;
    private int hitPoints;

    public PlayerCharacter() {
        defense = 5;
        hitPoints = 15;
    }

    public PlayerState receiveHit(int attackStrength) {
        int hitStrength = Math.Max(attackStrength - defense, 0);
        hitPoints = Math.Max(hitPoints - hitStrength, 0);

        return hitPoints > 0 ? PlayerState.Alive : PlayerState.Dead;
    }
}
```

You'll notice that there is no way for any other class to know what the `hitPoints` or `defense` values are.  The class is fully contained, making it opaque.  The method receives all the external information it needs as parameters.  This allows you to replace the very simplistic algorithm I have for calculating damage done with something more complex.  This class represents OOP from the traditional interpretation.

**Data Objects and Services (AKA Procedural with Objects)**

The JavaBean approach is very much like a C `struct`.  You have all your object state available outside of the class, allowing other objects to modify it's state directly.  It is entirely possible to write running applications that use this approach.  In fact, it's actually quite common these days.

In writing code for the server, it is very common for developers to use Object-Relational Mapping (ORM) tools like hibernate.  They bind database rows to POJOs, hiding the code to synchronize changes to the database.  Again, the JavaBean approach is used for binding, but this time to the back end.

Services are then written to manipulate the data objects (i.e. the name spaces for functions).

This approach is not traditional OOP, but it works very well for a certain class of applications.

**Your PHD Supervisor**

Your professor is trying to teach you proper OOP.  It's a valuable skill to have, and knowing the trade-offs will only help you build better systems in the future.  There is a lot of strength in the traditional OOP approach, since it does lend itself better to reuse.

It's better to have more, but smaller self-contained objects with your professor.  It also makes your code easier to spot errors in.

When you get in the real world, you'll have to make decisions based on how your team designed the code to work.

Comment: Well, I'm glad *someone* brought their magic 8 ball this morning.

Comment: Except of splitting variables into different classes is there another way? (I am using a framework and I use the classes that I should use, it is hard to split them to different classes)

Comment: @Novemberland: You have to identify what your PhD Supervisor means by "ugly" first.  "Ugly" all by itself is not actionable; I've seen a whole lot of ugly code in my time that still does its job.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've edited ugly to not readable...

Comment: @Novemberland: I think you still need to ask your PhD Supervisor to be more specific.  Is the problem too many variables?  Something else?

Comment: @Novemberland, In Java, you can use local variables within methods, similar to how your PhD supervisor writes the C++ code.

Comment: On a side note, if you have 99 elements in your POJO you probably haven't thought about your problem domain properly.  As @RobertHarvey mentioned, communicating with your PhD supervisor is a good idea.  My answer is based on your example code and your comments about the Supervisor's code.